# Pass Data from VF section on detail page to standard Save button

Tags: visualforce, page-layout, lookup-filter, dynamic-vf-component, save-and-new

The initial requirement is to create a Dependent Look Up so that when one look up is clicked it will control the values of second dependent look up.

**What I have done**: Created a VF page and a custom look up. Added this VF page as a section in standard Account Page Layout.

**Problem**: I want to save the VF section with the Standard Account fields. How to achieve this?

I can provide more clarity and code if required.

Comment: Adding the code would be helpful..

Comment: Also you should know that VF pages embedded on the standard page cannot talk to each other because they are served from different domains. There are workaround (postMessages) for this, but it has browser compatibility issues.